# Picam noir issue

Tags: raspicam, mmal

when I try to take a picture using my Pi Camera this error message is returned:

```
raspistill -o image.jpg

mmal: mmal_vc_component_enable: failed to enable component: ENOSPC
mmal: camera component couldn't be enabled
mmal: main: Failed to create camera component
mmal: Failed to run camera app. Please check for firmware updates
```

How can I solve this problem? And why is this error returned?

The camera is already enabled and memory is already split by 128 in `config.txt`

Comment: nobody can you help me Please?

Comment: I'm not sure, but you may need to 'sudo' that command...

Comment: Have you checked the ribbon connectors on the camera and the pi?  If they are out of alignment or pulling loose the system should failsafe like this.  @BobT sudo is not required for that command.

Answer (score 0):

The camera may be running out of GPU memory.

Check `config.txt` in the `/boot/` folder. The `gpu_mem` option should be at least 128. Alternatively, use the Memory Split option in the Advanced section of raspi-config to set this.